# changing style.css makes no difference

Tags: html, css

EDIT 1: It seems people don't exactly understand what I mean. No matter what I change in style.css it makes no difference. I tried making the text red just because it was the first colour I thought of when trying to fix it but it still makes no difference. I've got black text with the default font on a red background but the background is only red because I changed it in the html and not style.css. Nothing at all in the style.css registers, even after clearing the cache and opening in incognito mode.

---

EDIT 2: I've been messing around with it more and when I reload the page with the Network open at the bottom of my browser I've noticed that I have a 404 error which I assume means the problem is how I've linked it, but I don't see any problem there, as both the html file and style.css are in the same folder, with no other folders separating them.

```html
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
  <title>Lèsè eSports</title>
 </head>
```

---

I'm having a problem getting my style.css to work with my html. They are in the same folder and I've been messing around with it a lot trying to figure out what I've done wrong, but I can't seem to see it (I'm still pretty new to this). Here's a few random things I've currently got in my style.css. I'm just trying to get anything to work but so far all i have is a red background.

```css
body {
  color: red;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

h1 {
  border: 5px solid;
}
```

```html
<body style="background-color: red">
  <h1 class="red">Lèsè eSports</h1>
</body>
```

Comment: `color` in your css is text color, so you have red text over red background. That's why you don't see it

Comment: Clear all cache, Restart browser and also try in private search browser. all the best.

Comment: yes make either font color red or body color red.

Comment: ive changed the colour of both the text and background. that isnt the problem. problem is that anything i put in style.css does not make changes to the website. i can still see the text, its on my website but just black text on a red background. everything ive got in the snippet of my style.css is just a few things ive tried but it still made no difference at all

Comment: Well "*black text on a red background*"  is quite different from "*all I have is a red background*". Is your `.css` file spelled the exact same way as in the `<link>` line in your `html` header?

Comment: yeah its exactly the same. it seems to all be linked correctly but its as if it doesnt even exist

Answer (score 0):

It seems that css must be getting loaded but you are not able to differentiate as both body color and font color is red.
you can modify this part of code to see the css

```
.red {
  color: black;
}
```

Even then if it does not work,just clear browser cache and reload.

Comment: it still isnt changing anything. ive tried reloading without the cache as well but no matter what i put in my style.css there is no change. its just the default black font with no border. also, i only tried making the text red just to see if i could get anything at all working but had no luck

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have reload page without cache, by press Ctrl + F5 (or open browser in incognito)

Comment: still no luck. i opened in incognito too but its still the same. i deleted my style.css and started over with it but still nothing is changing. only thing i can think of is a linking problem but it seems like its right